# PHP - get string between two quotes more times

Tags: php, replace

I have string

```
$string = '<b>My name is "David"</b>. My girlfriend is <b>"Tessi"</b> This text is only example. I want to get only words "between two quotes".';`
```

I need replace all inside `"` with custom HTML div:

```
<div class="name_replaced">HERE_PUT_WORD_FROM_QUOTES</div>
```

So, finally string must be:

```
$string = '<b>My name is <div class="name_replaced">David</div></b>. My girlfriend is <b><div class="name_replaced">Tessi</div></b> This text is only example. I want to get only words <div class="name_replaced">between two quotes</div>.';`
```

How?

Comment: will there be the chance that there will be other quotes appearing elsewhere in the string? Will there be a chance that there will be an odd number of quotes in the string?

Comment: use a DOM parser, e.g. http://php.net/dom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are code using `preg_replace` function described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$string = '<b>My name is "David"</b>. My girlfriend is <b>"Tessi"</b> This text is only example. I want to get only words "between two quotes".';

$string = preg_replace('/"(.*?)"/i', '<div class="name_replaced">\1</div>', $string);
```

Comment: @MarcB In general case yes, I agree with you, but the question refers all strings inside quotes without any exceptions so I think the answer is matching all solution conditions.

Comment: `<a href="toby.php">` will now become `<a href=<div class="name_replaced">toby.php</div>">`. not exactly valid.

Comment: @MarcB I know what you are talking about and agree with you completely, but the question doesn't explain whether there may be more html tags except simple formating like B, U or I. The answer could be as good as the question is.

Comment: The `i` modifier makes no sense.  A lazy quantifier is not best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple `preg_replace()` could do the trick. The code Snippet below shows how:

```
        <?php
            $string         = '<b>My name is "David"</b>. My girlfriend is <b>"Tessi"</b> This text is only example. I want to get only words "between two quotes".';
            $wordsBW2Quotes = preg_replace("#([\"'])([\w\s]+)([\"'])#", "$2", $string);

            var_dump($string);
            var_dump($wordsBW2Quotes);

           // FIRST VAR_DUMP PRODUCES:
           // '<b>My name is "David"</b>. My girlfriend is <b>"Tessi"</b> This text is only example. I want to get only words "between two quotes".' (length=132)

           // SECOND VAR_DUMP PRODUCES:
           // '<b>My name is David</b>. My girlfriend is <b>Tessi</b> This text is only example. I want to get only words between two quotes.' (length=126)
```

Test it out [Here](https://eval.in/607272).

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<b>My name is "David"</b>. My girlfriend is <b>"Tessi"</b> This text is only example. I want to get only words "between two quotes".';`


$newString = str_replace('"', '</div>', str_replace('"', '<div class="name_replaced">', $string));
```

Comment: Your code provide incorrect output. Did you run it? When you do  `var_dump($newString)` then you will get `string(348) "<b>My name is <div class=</div>name_replaced</div>>David<div class=</div>name_replaced</div>></b>. My girlfriend is <b><div class=</div>name_replaced</div>>Tessi<div class=</div>name_replaced</div>></b> This text is only example. I want to get only words <div class=</div>name_replaced</div>>between two quotes<div class=</div>name_replaced</div>>."`

Comment: No and have no idea how to provide correct solution with `str_replace` function in this case.

Comment: Simply str_replace will not resolve this issue, you need to use preg_replace as you have mentioned above.